# Инициализация статическим методом или статическим блоком в Java?

Tags: java, static, инициализация

Подскажите, как правильно инициализировать статические переменные?

```
private static final String statStr;
static {
   statStr = "testStr";
}
```

или

```
private static final String statStr = initStatStr();
private String initStatStr() {
   return "testStr";
}
```

Comment: правильно - никак, и тот и другой способ допустим, но лучше не использовать статику

Comment: Если совсем не использовать статику, то нужно будет значительную часть Core самого языка выпилить)

Answer (score 1):

Вам правильно сказали. Лучше вообще избегать статики, но если все же по-другому невозможно, то вариант со статический блоком будет предпочтительнее

1. Уменьшается кол-во методов классов (пусть даже приватных)
2. Средствами рефлексии проще вытащить приватный метод, чем статический
   блок
3. Выполнить содержимое статического блока средствами рефлексии
   намного мложнее, чем приватный метод

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос (перенес из комментария) -

> правильно - никак, и тот и другой способ допустим, но лучше не
>   использовать статику

Мои 5 копеек по поводу статики...

**Cтатику сложно, если не невозможно, переинициализировать.**

Класс, единожды загруженный класс-лоадером и имеющий внутри себя что то вроде 
`private static final SimpleDateFormat = "...";` 
на все время работы приложения будет с этим жить, я называю это "**прибить гвоздями**".

Теперь что делать чтобы это поведение изменить извне? Начиная от

> как в юнит тестах подсунуть мок-объект вместо
>   <подставить_нужное_имя_класса>?

и до

> как в этой библиотеке поменять локализацию?

Еще есть такой аспект, что если статика не будет проинициализирована по каким-либо причинам, то класс-лоадер не сможет загрузить класс и упадет `ClassNotFoundException`, что первое время пустит Вас по ложному пути при отладке.

И как вишенка на торте - **статика никогда не будет съедена garbage collector-ом**.